Background not visible behind the "whitespace" of a Unicode Character
I am using a sunburst behind a unicode character (eye, &#128065), with a CSS of:
.the-eye{
    width:100%;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px #eeee11;
}

HTML:
<span class="the-eye">&#128065;</span>
However, instead of a clean yellow background behind it, I see a white circle which appears to be rendered as part of the eye graphic.  Is there a way to make that white part of the unicode transparent?

Verified on Chrome and Firefox.

box-shadow is drown from the edge of an element. you maybe want drop-shadow and repeat it a few times instead box-shadow: filter:drop-shadow(0 0 20px  #eeee11) drop-shadow(0 0 20px  #eeee11) drop-shadow(0 0 20px  #eeee11) drop-shadow(0 0 20px  #eeee11);

Just set the background-color to the same as the box-shadow?

background + box-shadow leaves often a thiny transparent gap in between bg and shadow :(

Note; from the clues of the helpful people here, I now understand the unicode character was transparent.  The box-shadow just wasn't covering the center of the background.  Changing the background color to match took care of it.

@Paulie_D is correct: set the background-color to the same as the shadow.


.the-eye{
    width:100%;
    border-radius:50%;
    font-size: 50pt;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px #eeee11;
    background-color: #eeee11;
}
<span class="the-eye">&#128065;</span>




All of the answers worked, but just adding the background-color was the simplest solution.  Thank you!

You're welcome! I feel that Paulie_D should get the credit

from earlier comment:

box-shadow is drown from the edge of an element. you maybe want drop-shadow and repeat it a few times instead box-shadow: filter:drop-shadow(0 0 20px  #eeee11) drop-shadow(0 0 20px  #eeee11) drop-shadow(0 0 20px  #eeee11) drop-shadow(0 0 20px  #eeee11);

demo below:


.the-eye {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 7em;
  color:#018af8;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px #eeee11) drop-shadow(0 0 20px #eeee11) drop-shadow(0 0 20px #eeee11) 
}

/* demo purpose */
html {
  background:#333333;
  min-height:100vh;
  display:grid;
  place-content:center;
}
<span class="the-eye">&#128065;</span>




this also works

@YvonneAburrow , as i also commented, shadow might come with a little bug on the edges ;) https://i.sstatic.net/BOnjHhKz.png  and is also drawn from the boxe . drop-shadow takes transparent parts into account. there are different . no need of a border-radius here for example . depends on what the op expects ;)

that is why I made the eye bigger, to see if it had the effect you mention - looks OK to me. (Results may vary depending on operating system)

@YvonneAburrow the img linked shows a lightgray circle on the edges ;) . but that's only if it bothers the op . These bugs about shadows will disappear some day, it already improved.

I am on a Mac and using Google Chrome where it looks OK... what OS are you using?

@YvonneAburrow Firefox latest, i like it better ;)

To avoid the gap you just need to apply box shadow to an element with zero height and width, In this case another absolutely positioned span would do, and then set the z-index of that backdrop to -1 to fall under the icon.
This may not be the best solution but it is a solution, especially if support for older browsers is a concern.


span.the-eye {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
}

span.the-eye .backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 24px #eeee11;
  z-index: -1;
}
<span class="the-eye"> &#128065; <span class="backdrop"/><span/>



[EDIT]
This can also work with pseudo elements


.the-eye {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.the-eye:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 24px #eeee11;
  z-index: -1;
}
<span class="the-eye">&#128065;<span/>




Why use an extra element? Just use a pseudo-element instead! https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/RwmBggv

@Paulie_D Pseudo element works as well, The idea remains the same
